# Check field's data availability in WHERE clause

Tags: soql, where

Can we make a check on WHERE clause of a SOQL query for comparing 2 date fields availability? My requirement is, I want to get the response from query based on data availability on two different fields. I have 2 date fields (Date_A__c and Date_B__c). My requirement is to make a check on a single query that if data is present in Date_A__c, the query should return with its data, but if data is unavailable in Date_A__c, the query should return with Date_B__c data. Is this condition possible to write in WHERE clause.

Comment: You can not do this in a query using just those two field. You can create a formula field that evaluates to the correct value and use that in your query.

Comment: @KhushbooDua why you can not use a formula field in a where condition!?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it with SOQL. But you can do it for sure with APEX method use a SOQL query.
A SOQL query reads data from a data store based on conditions you enter. The APEX method returns the data:

```
public Date myMethod()
{
    MyObject__c m = [Select Date_A__c, Date_B__c
                     From MyObject__c
                     Where CreatedDate = LAST_WEEK];
    if(m.Date_A__c != null)
    {
        return m.Date_A__c;
    }

    return m.Date_B__c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using single query.

Make your query

```
WHERE Date_A__c != null OR Date_B__c != null
```

and when you iterate over it then simply put an if condition

```
if(Object.Date_A__c != null) {
    //run code here
}
else {
    //run code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a purely SOQL query then I think you can create a custom formula field (checkbox) can use that in the query.

Otherwise, you will have to use apex to filter the data which some folks have already mentioned in other comments.